# How to integrate/combine python + java backend to html + css frontend?

Tags: java, python, html, frontend, backend

Hello there developers!

I'm trying to make a project. Its basically a web application which has few functions like converting PDF to image, OCR, etc.

I made the frontend using HTML, CSS and in the backend, I used python in some parts and java in other parts.

How do I combine the frontend with backend? I tried finding but didn't understand how to do that. Can anyone help with this?

Thank you :)

Comment: I would suggest using a single language as it would ease deployment and decrease the count of things that would be needed to deployed. Although it totally depends on the type of project. As for connecting backend with frontend you will need an WebAPI to connect them. You can build a Web API with both Java or Python with latter being the easy one out of both.

Comment: Okay I changed the whole backend code to python. Will search about Web API.

Answer (score 0):

You need JS code on the client side to send requests to the server via specific routes.Or you must distribute static files from your server. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/), [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).